# Why is Scrapy Spider not following the next page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

my code is not working on the next page. It just scrapes the first page and doesn't follow the next page link. I am using an anaconda virtual environment.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import logging

class Dgoodyman16Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dgoodyman16'
    allowed_domains = ['www.medicregister.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.medicregister.com/USA/list/suppliers.asp']

    def parse(self, response):
        all_lists = response.xpath('//a[@class="TopicHeaderSupplier"]')
        for lists in all_lists:
            title = lists.xpath('.//text()').get()
            links = lists.xpath('.//@href').get()


            yield response.follow(url=links, callback=self.parse_lists, meta={'lists_title': title})

    def parse_lists(self, response):

        title = response.request.meta['lists_title']

        for data in response.xpath('//div[@class="vcard"]'):
            raw_html = data.xpath('.//div[@style="line-height: 1.5;"]').extract()
            tel = data.xpath('.//span[@class="tel"]/text()').get()
            # email = response.xpath('(//div[@class="vcard"]/a)[2]/@href').get()


        yield {
            'Title': title,
            'html': raw_html,
            'Phone': tel
        }

        next_page = response.xpath('((//div[@class="margin-5"])[2]/a)[10]').get()
        if next_page:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Better yet just put the full list into start_urls:

```
start_urls = ['https://www.medicregister.com/USA/Manufacturers/Suppliers/Page%d/cid.htm' % i for i in range(1,730)]
```

This is way faster than following next pages, which wouldn't happen asynchronously

Comment: That's really bad decision since number of page can be changed over time.

Comment: @Michael, you  can get the first page and do the math, I left that out for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider to collect all URLs in the navigation, remove the duplicates, and follow all of them? The URLs in the set are valid.

```python
relative_urls = set(
    response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "margin-5")]/a/@href').getall()
)
absolute_urls = {
    response.urljoin(url) for url in relative_urls
}
```

---

I suggest that you open a scrapy shell, fetch the URL given in your start_urls, and reexamine your *unique* xpath. If it doesn't return a relative URL, you know why the scraper stops here.

Comment: The XPath expression I am using is unique. So, I don't think there will be an issue with duplicates since there are no duplicate links.